# "This view does not support selection" error on VBA Excel when copy-pasting and resizing charts on Powerpoint slides

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, copy-paste

I am working on a project to automate powerpoint presentations. For this, I create charts on Excel and then I use VBA codes to copy and paste them on an existing powerpoint template.

However, when I try to resize and position my charts, I encounter the following problem: "Selection (unknown member) : Invalid request. This view does not support selection."

Here is my code :

```
Sub powerpoint()

            Dim Powerpointapp As PowerPoint.Application
            Dim PowerPointPrsn As PowerPoint.Presentation
            Dim cht As ChartObject
            Dim strpath As String
            Dim rng As Range
            Dim mySlide As Object
            Dim myShape As Object

    ' paths to wkb and template
            strpath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\template.pptm"
        
    ' create new ppt with template
            Set Powerpointapp = New PowerPoint.Application
            Set PowerPointPrsn = Powerpointapp.Presentations.Open(strpath)
            
     ' copy paste chart 1 to slide 1 and resizing 
        Set cht = Worksheets("sheet name").ChartObjects(1)
        cht.Copy
        DoEvents
        PowerPointPrsn.Slides(1).Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteMetafilePicture
        Powerpointapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 50
        Powerpointapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 120
        Powerpointapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 590
```

My issue is starting at the line

```
Powerpointapp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 50
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You use `Selection` without selecting , that's why you are running into this error. Here is .select method [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.chart.select). And some guy on GitHub posted that [VBA Excel Charts to PowerPoint](https://gist.github.com/wmtylerdavis/5879851)

Answer (score 0):

As p77u77n77k mentioned, you haven't selected anything, so referring to the .Selection object will throw an error. You could instead:

At the top of the module, DIM oSh as Shape

Then

```
Set oSh = PowerPointPrsn.Slides(1).Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)(1)

With oSh
   .Left = 50
   .Top = 120
   .Width = 590
End with
```

Note that I've used ppPasteEnhancedMetafile rather than ppPasteMetafilePicture. I'm  not sure what the diff is, but it seems to work better here. Microsoft's docs on this are all but useless. I suspect ppPasteMetafilePicture will give you a metafile rendition of whatever *picture* (ie raster image) is on the clipboard.